# Bitcoin Merkle Tree Verification / Development

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

Recently, I am doing research on bitcoin since it is fascinating. I came up with a few questions related to it that I would highly appreciate if someone can answer.

1. I do not understand how transactions can be verified by just using the Merkle Root. The block headers only contain the Merkle root, but to verify if the transactions in the block are valid, you still have to hash all of the transactions and compare it with the Merkle root. Am I missing something?
2. It seems like bitcoin source code can be updated: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md. If this is the case, how can we say that the bitcoin is permanent decentralized store of value? We don't know how the system will change in the future. Also, who is in charge of developing the bitcoin? If there is institution in charge of this, how can we say it is fully decentralized?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. The transaction identifier a.k.a. txid is generated by twice hashing (SHA-256) the serialized [transaction data](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/transaction-data). The [merkle root](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/merkle-root) is the result of a merkle tree which takes as inputs all txids in the block. To paraphrase this masterpiece website ([learnmeabitcoin](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/)):
   **"[Merkle root] gives you a short yet unique fingerprint for all the transactions in a block".**
2. Yes, the bitcoin source code can and has been updated for years. In Bitcoin history, there are plenty groups which has modified (forks) bitcoin source code and run another version of the [bitcoin repository](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin).
   Bitcoin forks are [listed](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5221882.0), some of them still running. We don't know how the system will change in the future, but if you don't like these changes, you are free to fork your own and aggregate a community around it.  **The community is crucial, the contributors (miners, developers, writers …) and users give strength to the project, as long as there is a community around bitcoin, it can exist.**

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It makes sense but I am not sure how Merkle root is efficient for verifying if transaction is included in the block. To check if transaction is in the block, you still have to hash all of the transactions and compare it to Merkle root, right?

Comment: @xor Merkle roots are great for proving if a transaction is in a block without downloading the entire block. To prove that a transaction is in a block, you only need to provide the hash of the transaction and a merkle path to the transaction from which the merkle proof can be built up.

This is great for light weight clients that do not have the storage capacity to download the entire blockchain but still need to make sure a transaction has taken place.